# how to update extern variable in C

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I have these files

**test1.h**

```
extern int value;
void inc_value();
int print_value();
```

**test1.c**

```
#include "test1.h"

int value=0;
void inc_value() 
{

printf("inc value from test3.c = %d\n", value++); 
}

int print_value() 
{

    printf(" value in test1.c  = %d\n", value);
    return value;
}
```

**test3.c**

```
# include "test1.h"

main()
{

inc_value();

}
```

**test4.c**

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include "test1.h"

main()

{
    printf("value from test4 = %d\n", print_value());
}
```

I'm updating variable "value" from test3.c and trying to read it from test4.c. However test3.c is unable to update the "value" that is declared in test1.h and defined in test1.c

What point am I missing here..

Comment: you have two `main`s? O'rlly?

Comment: yes 1st I invoke test3 to update the value and later test4 to print the updated value

Comment: those are two separate applications? you just made my day.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  You can't have two `main` routines in one program.

Comment: yes, they are two different applications

Comment: @suzanne: you cannot share variables between two processes (aka: two executables) using the "extern" keyword

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will never work.

You can't use an external variable from *two different programs* and magically expect it to work. It's just ... wrong. Each program runs in its own address space, and doesn't know anything about any other process' address spaces. There are techniques for doing this (look up interprocess communucation), but that's a whole different area.

The way `extern` works is that it allows you to access a variable defined in a different C file *within the same program*.

You seem to be mis-understanding at a quite fundamental level how the programs you are writing work and execute, since you expect this to work. I recommend reading up more on how C works, and also perhaps a bit on how operating systems host programs in order to run them.

One way of sharing information between programs like you describe is to store the data in a file, which is written by one program (the one that runs first) and read by the other, but that is quite tricky to get right, too.

Comment: In that case, is there any other way where I can update a "common" variable from test3.c and later use that updated variable from "test4.c

Comment: @suzanne Yes, you need something known as IPC, inter process communication. You should probably try to find other solutions because IPC is way beyond your current level of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `void inc_value()` from another file, you should declare it (probably in the header):

```
void inc_value();
```

If you want to directly access `value`, you can, as it was declared as an extern:

```
# include "test1.h"
main()
{
    value = 6;
}
```

Also note, that in current implementation of `inc_value`, the value will be incremented after it is passed to `printf`, e.g. the printed value will be the previous one.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add that here. but yes I'm declaring the functions in header file as well..

Comment: Yes, I'm able to update from test3.c but still reading from test4 is returing "0" instead of "1" when I  run test3 first and later test4

Answer (score -2):

You should put extern int value in the test3.c and just put int value in test1.h.Look at this link: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/  Hope this helps...